# Proper use of Sql timestamp field

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to have a waiting period field in a table and was wondering what is the correct data type is.

The admin will set them i.e level 1 must wait 1month to progress to level 2, level2 must wait 5months to progress to level etc. From the users registration date I should be able to see if they are allowed to progress. What is the correct datatype for the waiting period field

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter which one you use, just make sure you save a time stamp or just the date (and to be exact, time, you could always cutoff the time bit to get the date only) they registered.

With each you can determine their duration spend registered, current timestamp - registered timestamp or current date/time - registered date/time.

Comment: But the admin might want to change the waiting time for each level. So it isnt just setting the end time but the actual timeframe needed to wait. Maybe I dont understand what you wrote. Sorry